# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint - Not wrong data type

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So I have this code:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
set foreign_key_checks = 0;


# MAKE WAY FOR THE NEW
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `Winkelbezoek`;

CREATE DATABASE `Winkelbezoek` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `Winkelbezoek`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PERSOON` (
`BSN` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Leeftijd` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT
    PRIMARY KEY (`BSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `WINKEL` (
`Naam` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Plaats` varchar(40) DEFAULT 'Breda',
`Grootte` ENUM('Klein','Groot'),

CONSTRAINT
    PRIMARY KEY (`Naam`,`Plaats`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ISKLANTBIJ` (
`BSN` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Datum` date NOT NULL,
`Naam` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Plaats` varchar(40) DEFAULT 'Breda',

CONSTRAINT
    PRIMARY KEY (`datum`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`BSN`) REFERENCES PERSOON(`BSN`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Naam`) REFERENCES WINKEL(`Naam`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Plaats`) REFERENCES WINKEL(`Plaats`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I try to execute it in PHPmyadmin, it gives me an error: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

I did some searching, but the only thing I could find which could be wrond would be the inconsistant use of data types. I have triple checked them by now and I still cannot find what is going wrong here. Does anyone know what might be the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can use MYsql interface to create your base and then export the code .
It can help you if you don't know how to write code.

Comment: This is true, however does not help me, as I presumed I knew how to code.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t use foreign keys very much but changing the following removes the error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `WINKEL` (
`Naam` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`Plaats` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'Breda',
`Grootte` ENUM('Klein','Groot'),

CONSTRAINT
   PRIMARY KEY (`Naam`,`Plaats`),
   KEY (`Plaats`,`Naam`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I think the key fields need to be from the start of the key on the other table (IE you can`t use one from the end without those that precede it).